# android thread.join() not working as expected

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, android-volley

i'm trying to achieve the following: do a single synchronous http request using Volley's Futures in a background thread, and have the current thread wait for the background thread to finish, so it can later handle the http response.

What actually happens is that after the .join(), everything seems to hang and I never enter the breakpoints inside the runnable's run method or get through to any command after the join().

NOTE - the current thread is an activity class, and this specific function is of a Java class whose services are called by the activity. I am aware that .join() on a UI thread causes it to hang...but only until the background thread is finished, right? Well, when I use .wait() instead of .join(), the background thread finishes really fast. It's almost as if calling join doesn't let the background thread do it's job.

```
private String requestConversionRatesFromApi() throws InterruptedException
{
    final JSONObject[] localResponse = {null};
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            String url = "myurl";
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(_context);
            RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new JSONObject(), future, future);
            queue.add(request);

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = future.get();
                localResponse[0] = jsonObject; //doesn't get here either unless I'm using .wait() and then it happens really fast
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
    t.start();
    t.join();
    return "foo"; //Doesn't get here
}
```

Comment: You should have an error in the output of the logcat, you can't make network request on the main(UI) thread (activities, fragments, ...)

Comment: What is the point of having one thread start a new thread, and then do _nothing_ except wait for the new thread to finish? Why not simply do the work in the first thread?

Comment: @crgarridos I will check if I have an error and update. However, am I truly making a network request on the main thread? I thought that my main thread creates a new thread, ' t ', and ' t ' is the one that does the request, not the main one.

Comment: @jameslarge The point is what crgarridos said, that I cannot do network requests on the main thread, so I create a new one.

Comment: I'll admit, I don't know Android, but that advice doesn't make any sense. Any thread in a Java process is _able_ to do anything that any other thread is able to do. I bet that, If somebody told you the "main" thread "can't" do network I/O, what they really meant was, that the main thread _should not wait_ for network I/O. Your code makes the main thread wait. The fact that it's waiting for some other thread to do the I/O doesn't help. The waiting is what's bad, or... that's my guess, anyway. Like I said, I'm not an Android programmer.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes, it's not that the thread can't do network requests, but as far as android projects are concerned, if you attempt to do so you get the well named NetworkOnMainThread exception. It is just a small and short request so really waiting isn't an issue in this case. I don't argue that in general making the main thread wait is a good idea.

Comment: Makes sense now. Sorry I don't have any insight into your actual problem.